# How can i read the correct http Status Code

Tags: php, header, http-status-code-404

I want to check if a tumblr blog is expired or not . 
So I want to check if the http header give me a **404** or **200** status code.

I try it on this website: `webconfs.com/http-header-check.php` and it works fine

404 for expired and 200 for alive

My code works fine but I get always a status code from 302. And I don't know why?

If I check `https://unnachamlich.tumblr.com/` it sould be 200 and for example if I check `https://unnachamlich34534523.tumblr.com/` it should be 400

Here is my `php` code

```
$url = 'https://unnachamlich.tumblr.com/';

$headers=get_headers($url, 0);

echo $headers[0];
```

Can anyone help me that I get the right status code.

Comment: 302 is an HTTP redirect code, and if I put in the URL you provide, I do indeed get redirected, so get_headers is returning the correct code. Looks to be a tumblr redirect for getting user consent which I assume would set a cookie on tumblr.com so it only redirects once. It looks like this step may also require user input, so you might need to get creative here.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. yes but if you check it on this website : webconfs.com/http-header-check.php. And there it works . I dont understand why its working there.

Comment: I tried your code [here](http://www.writephponline.com/) and it gives me `200` and `404` status codes as expected

Comment: on your site it works, really strange.